# ¿Para qué sirve SASS en desarrollo web?

Tags: html, css, sass

Vi un video en donde usaban SASS para cambiar el css de una página, pero me dio mucha curiosidad ya que sentía que copiaban lo mismo de la hoja de css en la hoja scss, solo que agregando variables, entonces me confundí un poco.

Perdón por la ignorancia, pero no entiendo muy bien para que se utiliza si se copia lo mismo del archivo css o por lo menos eso vi del video.

Estoy intentando leer la documentación pero también me encuentro un poco perdida

Answer (score 2):

Como SASS es un lenguaje "Turing Complete" al satisfacer la Regla 110, puedes realizar cualquier calculo o programa computacional usándolo.

Por consecuencia podrías programar absolutamente todo lo que quisieras (con la justa dotación de HTML), y con programar me refiero a realmente programar, por ejemplo he visto gente hacer fractales y pintar el conjunto de mandelbrot.

CSS3 también es "Turing Complete".

Así que ¿Por qué usaríamos SASS en vez de CSS3?

Por muchos temas que ya tiene bien cuidados como:

- partials
- mixins
- pruebas unitarias

En la práctica además de esas bondaddes teóricas, básicamente nos ayuda con la organización, nos facilita una buena estructuración y fácil mantenimiento en comparación con hojas de estilo CSS3.

Answer (score 1):

Sass es un preprosesador CSS, lo que hace es agregar funcionalidades de programación que al final compila a un CSS plano.

Un ejemplo claro es la creación de variables, aunque ahora ya puedes declarar variables en CSS nativo; otra de las funcionalidades son los mixins que funcionan básicamente como las funciones en un lenguaje de programación.

Bueno, al final del día es un **preprosesador css**;  busca algo más de información con ese término en Google que seguro te lo puede explicar mucho más claro que yo.